# join a bigger data set to a smaller one keeping the number of rows of the smaller in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an F1 Data Frame with pit stops called `pitStops`:

```
DriverId  stop lap
  1          1   3
  2          1   4
  3          1   3
  4          1   2
```

and I have another data frame with the driver position lap by lap called `posLap`:

```
driverId lap Position
    1      1     1
    1      2     1
    1      3     3
    1      4     3
    2      1     2
    2      2     2
    2      3     2
    2      4     5
```

When I do a `merge` or a `left_join` or any kind of join the pit stop data frame increases in the amount of rows hap because R is coercing to character vector.
the code i have written is the following:

`AllAusPit2017 = inner_join(AllAusPit2017, AllAusPos2017, by = "driverId", "lap")`

I am doing the join based on `driverId` and `lap`
what I would like to see is the following:

```
driverId stop  lap position
    1      1     3     3
    2      1     4     5
```

and so on for the rest of the drivers. Is this something that R can do? Please let me know if I have not explained myself correctly.

Comment: Please show the code your trying to use. A `dplyr::left_join` such as `left_join(pitStops, posLap,by=c("DriverId"="driverId","lap"))` should work.

Comment: @Jul line of code added mate. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
AllAusPit2017 = left_join(AllAusPit2017, AllAusPos2017, by = c("DriverId" = "driverId", "lap"))
```

When joining on multiple columns, the argument needs to submitted as a vector. Your original code only took "driverId" into account.

Comment: You'd need an `inner_join` to exclude the third and fourth rows of `pitStops`